# different row height for mobile using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the main page of my website (oil-sheikh.com) I have a big image that is 100% width of the page and 80 % height.
When looking on it in a mobile device the image the should be only be 50% of the height (and 100% width)
I used bootstrap to built it the web-site.
How can I set the css that the row will be height limited only on col-xs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered media specific css? So put your css for mobile devices like so

```
@media (max-width:480px){
    .someClass{ /*all css for .someClass here*/}
}
```